# How can the following Gaussian integral be calculated?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function, gaussian-integral

How can we compute this integral? 
$$\int_{1.96}^{\infty} e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} \ dx$$

Comment: [Here's a tutorial in MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: This corresponds to a standard normal random variable, and we wish to compute $P(Z > 1.96)$. Tables give this to be about 0.05.

Comment: i think hes missing a sqrt(1/2pi) right for it to be standard normal? so the answer would be about 0.05*sqrt(2pi)

Comment: Hey I think the 0.05 part is not quite correct. Since the pdf above is of a standard normal distribution, and its being integrated from 1.96, the answer should include 0.025, not 0.05.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$ e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} $$ is almost the pdf of the standard normal, we are missing a factor of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$. So we can simply multiply by the factor times its reciprocal so we dont end up messing up the final 
$$\sqrt{2\pi}\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} dx$$.

The x's are the stadard normal random variables, also known as Z scores. From a Z table you can see that Z = 1.96 is about the 95% percentile.

So the missing area is 1-0.95 = 0.05 between Z = -1.96 and Z= 1.96 since the normal table is symmetric. But we only care about the right hand side, from Z= 1.96 to infinity, so the area under this integral $$\int_{1.96}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} dx$$ ends up being 0.025. We need to times this by $$\sqrt{2\pi}$$ to get the final answer which is around 0.063.

Comment: I saw the answer to this somewhere as 0.025(2pi)^(1/2). Should one use standard normal distribution or Gamma distribution for the above question?

Comment: Hey I just checked standard normal distribution pdf, so your method is absolutely correct, just that the final answer is missing a 0.025 which is the area lying to the right of 1.96 under the standard normal curve

Comment: hey sorry for the delay i updated the answer, that was a very good point.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

By definition of the [Error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) one primitive is:

$$\int e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mbox{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)
$$

and
$$
\lim _{x \to +\infty}\mbox{erf}(x)=1
$$

Comment: Sorry. There was a mistake in the square root argument !